# Continuous map between sphere and hemisphere

Tags: general-topology

The homeomorphism between $S^1$ and $S^1/z \sim -z$ is given by the map $f(z) = z^2$. I can see why it is one-to-one, but how to rigorously show that it is continuous? It is obvious that it is continuous on the whole $\mathbb{R^2} = \mathbb{C}$ but I am not sure that a restriction of the continuous map to any subset is continuous too.

Comment: You define continuity locally. I mean $\varphi$ is continuous on $X$ iff it is continuous in the neighbourhood of each $x\in X$. And so the restriction of a continuous function is contnuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Continuity is a local property so if you see it is continuous on the whole $\mathbf{C}$ you should be able to see it is continuous on any subset.

And just to be more precise, the homeomorphism is the composition of $S^1 \rightarrow S^1$ given by $z \mapsto z^2$ with the quotient map $S^1 \rightarrow S^1/\sim$.

The first map is continuous because it's a polynomial and the second map is continuous by definition. The composition of two continuous maps is continuous.

Side note about the title: $S^1/\sim$ is not quite a hemisphere regarded as a subset of $S^1$. It is a hemisphere with endpoints identified ($z \sim -z$).

Answer (score 1):

A good source for basic theorems on constructions of continuous functions is the textbook of Munkres on "Topology". He proves rigorously, for example, that for any topological spaces $X,Y$, any continuous function $f : X \to Y$, and any subsets $A \subset X$ and $B \subset Y$ such that $f(A)\subset B$, the domain and range restriction $f : A \to B$ is continuous with respect to the subspace topologies on $A$ and $B$.